# "Emprunt de" et "emprunté à" : pourquoi les différentes propositions ?

Tags: usage, prépositions, nuance

> Il s’agit d’un **emprunt de** l’anglais serendipity. [http://www.academie-francaise.fr/serendipite]
>
> **Emprunté à** l’anglais serendipity, dérivé de Serendippo, nom choisi par Cristoforo Armeno parmi les multiples noms donnés à l’île de Taprobane (aujourd’hui Sri Lanka). [https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/s%C3%A9rendipit%C3%A9]

Pourquoi les différentes prépositions (emprunt de et emprunté à) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Je vais emprunter le fil de ma réponse au dictionnaire de l'Académie Française car il me semble que sur cet article ce dictionnaire reflète bien l'usage actuel.

**Sens premier** : on emprunte de l'argent **à** quelqu'un : c'est un prêt, l'argent sera rendu (du moins celui qui prête y compte bien).
L'emploi de **de** dans ce sens est considéré [comme vieilli](https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/A9E1218).

- Nous avons emprunté de l'argent **à** la banque.

Bien entendu le **de** qui figure dans « de l'argent » dans la phrase d'exemple ci-dessus n'a rien à voir avec l'emploi d'une quelconque préposition après *emprunter*, il s'agit ici de l'article partitif puisqu'on peut le remplacer par un déterminant :

- Nous avons emprunté une grosse somme à la banque.

**Au sens figuré** (prendre quelque chose à autrui et le faire sien) les deux se rencontrent et le choix entre **de** et  **à** est une question de niveau de langue :

- Le mot sérendipité est emprunté à l'anglais/est un emprunt à l'anglais. (courant)
- Le mot sérendipité est emprunté de l'anglais/est un emprunt de l'anglais. (littéraire)
- J'ai emprunté le substrat de ma réponse du dictionnaire de l'Académie Française.

Answer (score 3):

Considérons d'abord le contexte grammatical le plus complet de ce mot.

- emprunt **de** qqc **à** qqu **par** qqu

« De » introduit la chose empruntée, « à » la personne qui fournit la chose et « par » celle qui en bénéficie. Il est rare de trouver les trois possibilités ensemble mais « emprunt **de** qqc **à** qqu » n'est pas rare. Dans cet usage à deux prépositions il n'est pas question de remplacer « à » par « de », l'expression serait incorrecte.

Il n'y a aucun problème avec « à », c'est une préposition courante dans ce contexte.

La forme « emprunt de » est assez bizarre si on n'a pas une grande habitude du langage ; lorsque  « de » est utilisé on trouve  le plus souvent un complément prépositionnel qui entre avec le nom dans une relation  de complément d'objet ou  de complément d'agent, ou de complément de nom et non une relation de complément d'attribution (ici, aspect antonyme).

*complément d'objet*

- Après avoir appris (...) que l'or avait doublé de prix (...) et que des spéculateurs étaient arrivés à Angers pour en acheter, le vieux vigneron, par un simple **emprunt de chevaux** fait à ses fermiers, se mit en mesure d'aller y vendre le sien…
- Faire un **emprunt de trois millions**;

*complément d'agent*

- emprunt **de** la ville de Paris, **de** la S.N.C.F

*complément de nom (caractérisation)*

- un emprunt **de** guerre

Cependant, on trouve d'autres exemples, comme [celui-ci](https://books.google.fr/books?id=M4qWBQAAQBAJ&pg=PT641&dq=%22emprunt+de+l%27%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1-df-593kAhWxyYUKHZlDCVk4UBDoAQg5MAM#v=onepage&q=%22emprunt%20de%20l'%22&f=false).

- traçabilité n. fém. Emprunt **de** l'anglais (dérivé de « to trace » : repérer). Il a été francisé.

On doit conclure que « de » peut être utilisé avec « emprunt » dans le sens de « dont l'élément constitutif a son origine dans/chez/…  » : « *un emprunt qui provient de l'anglais* ».

Après une révision de cette réponse je m'aperçois qu'elle vise plutôt jusqu'ici à justifier l'exactitude de l'usage mais néglige le point final, « Pourquoi utiliser plusieurs prépositions ? », même si elle introduit déjà la base des éventualités que l'on peut invoquer. Il n'y a pas de réponse précise pour une telle question, comme il n'y a pas de système qui laisse de trace d'une décision (presque toujours le cas) et comme l'usage nait sous la plume et dans la parole de ses utilisateurs.

On sait tout d'abord qu'un contexte matériel peut parfois être abordé conceptuellement de plusieurs façons. C'est bien le cas pour le mot emprunt : on peut envisager généralement le fait de l'emprunt sous l'aspect de l'octroi temporaire par une entité donné, d'où la préposition « à » ; lorsque l'usage est figuré, comme dans la question de l'introduction de mots étrangers dans une langue, on s'aperçoit que l'idée d'octroi ou d'attribution n'est plus  pertinente du tout et que c'est l'idée d'origine qui a le plus de sens. Cela bien sûr joue dans le processus de choix des mots chez le scripteur et donc le choix assez justifiable de « de » pour marquer une origine se serait insinué dans la langue sans pouvoir être rejeté. Je ne peux pas vérifier cela mais ce choix semblerait n'être  jamais fait dans le cas de l'usage littéral, la préposition étant toujours « à ». Il n'en reste pas moins que « à » est toujours correct dans l'emploi figuré qui nous occupe, cela très probablement en raison de son usage solide lorsque le mot « emprunt » est utilisé littéralement.

Comment: La question ne demandait pas  « pourquoi utiliser plusieurs prépositions » mais « pourquoi différentes prépositions ».

Comment: @Laure Ça revient à la même chose.

Comment: Pas du tout. Plusieurs peuvent être utilisés à la fois. Mais différentes implique l'une ou l'autre (et c'est ce qui est demandé dans la question).

Answer (score 0):

Emprunter quelque chose c’est le recevoir et prêter quelque chose c’est le donner. Ex Jean n’a pas d’argent, il est allé expliquer cela à Pierre et celui-ci le lui prête. Dans ce cas, on peut dire: Jean emprunte de l’argent à Pierre ou Pierre prête de l’argent à Jean. Celui qui prête s’appelle prêteur et celui qui emprunte s’appelle emprunteur.
J’espère que ma démarche vous sera utile.
Sovenel Dorval.

Comment: Et les prépositions ?  Cela ne répond pas directement à la question.  Voici le [tour] du site et bienvenue sur French Language SE.